# Oracle SELECT : Count of events per team and per year

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

As said in the title, I want to select the number of events per team and per year. The select statement below works fine but doesn't give me exactly what I am looking for.

```
SELECT
 Team.team_id,
 TO_CHAR(Event.START_DATE_TIME, 'yyyy') AS year,
 count(event_id)    AS events
FROM
 Team
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 Event ON Event.team_id = Team.team_id
GROUP BY
 TO_CHAR(Event.START_DATE_TIME, 'yyyy'),
 team_id
ORDER BY
 year  ASC,
 team_id  ASC
;
```

With this, if we have :

```
Team 1 : 1 event in 2006
Team 2 : 1 event in 2007
```

We obtain :

```
ID | Year | Events
------------------
1  | 2006 | 1
2  | 2007 | 1
```

And I would like to obtain :

```
ID | Year | Events
-------------------
1  | 2006 | 1
2  | 2006 | 0
1  | 2007 | 0
2  | 2007 | 1
```

I don't know how to modify my request to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not Oracle here to test, but in general this should work:

```
SELECT
 Team.team_id,
 Years.year,
 COALESCE(count(Event.event_id),0) events
FROM
 Team
   JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date_time) year FROM Event) Years ON 1=1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Event ON Event.team_id = Team.team_id AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Event.start_date_time) = Years.year
GROUP BY
 Years.year,
 team_id
ORDER BY
 year  ASC,
 team_id  ASC
;
```

You will get results for every year, where you have an event in the events. If that's not enough, you can replace the Years sub with a table filled with all the years.

Comment: The OP wants to see the years for which there aren't any events, so you can't rely on the `EVENT` table.

Comment: Hence the last comment. He didn't state that btw, and it might also be the case that there is always at least one event for the years he wants to see (I have no way of knowing that :) ).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
   SELECT x.team_id,
          x.year,
          COALESCE(COUNT(e.event_id), 0) AS events
     FROM (SELECT :start_year + LEVEL - 1 AS year,
                  t.team_id
             FROM DUAL, TEAM t
       CONNECT BY :start_year + LEVEL - 1 <= :end_year) x
LEFT JOIN EVENT e ON EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.start_date_time) = x.year
                 AND e.team_id = x.team_id
```

This will generate a list of years, but you have to set the `:start_year` and `:end_year` BIND variables.

Previously:

```
   SELECT x.team_id,
          x.year,
          COALESCE(COUNT(e.event_id), 0) AS events
     FROM (SELECT 2006 AS year,
                  a.team_id
             FROM TEAM a
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 2007,
                  b.team_id
             FROM TEAM b) x
LEFT JOIN EVENT e ON EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.start_date_time) = x.year
                 AND e.team_id = x.team_id
```

TO_CHAR is OK to get the year, but returns it as a CHAR(4) so you need to use `TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date_col, 'yyyy'))` to get a number.  So I used [EXTRACT](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php) instead...

Comment: I want it to be automatic. I don't want to write the years by hand.Thanks for the tip with extract.

Answer (score 1):

So it works ! :)
Here is my final query :

```
SELECT
 Team.name,
 Years.year,
 count(Event.event_id)
FROM
    Team
JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date_time) AS year
        FROM Event
    ) Years ON 1 = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Event ON    Event.team_id = Team.team_id
                AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Event.start_date_time) = Years.year
WHERE
    event_type = 'C'
GROUP BY
    Team.name,
    Years.year
ORDER BY
    Year ASC,
    name ASC
;
```

Thank you !